# Computing: $ \sum \frac{k! }{k^k} = 1.87985 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Applying Stirling's formula, one gets: $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi k} {(\frac{k}{e})}^k}{k^k} \approx \sqrt{2\pi k} \ e^{-k} $ which is definetely a sharp approximation for bigger $k$ however rather "weak" for "small" $k$.

This leads to: $ \sum \frac{\sqrt{2\pi k} {(\frac{k}{e})}^k}{k^k} \approx \sum \sqrt{2\pi k} \ e^{-k} $ with the last approx being rather crude.

Also comparing the results from wolframalpha: [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k+%3D+1+to+infty+of+k%21+%2F+k%5Ek) and [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k+%3D+1+to+infty+of+sqrt%282*pi*k%29+*e%5E%28-k%29).

Since the number computed by wolfram alpha looks kinda neat, I believe there is a nice solution to this. I would be happy about any sort of constructive comment, hint, solution or recommendation for further reading. 
As always thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems useful: sophomore's dream: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: The ratio between successive terms is $(1-\frac1{k+1})^k$ which converges monotonically to $e^{-1}$. This should allow you to bound the error term between two geometric series -- probably you don't need many explicit terms to get the five decimals in your question title.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes I will try that: I also found a closed form now: 
http://vixra.org/pdf/1510.0098v1.pdf - however this result seems to not be trivial

Comment: The value looks pretty messy if you go beyond 5 decimal places: $1.8798538621752585335...$ $$$$ Wolfram Mathematica doesn't generate a closed form for it.

Comment: This is [OEIS A$094082$](http://oeis.org/A094082).